# Meaning of "I" in a table in a study poster

Tags: cancer, terminology, clinical-study

From a poster to a [study](https://ascopubs.org/doi/abs/10.1200/JCO.2020.38.15_suppl.9048):

> [image]

I don't understand the meaning of "**I**" used in several fields of this table. What could it mean? I've read [the abstract](https://ascopubs.org/doi/abs/10.1200/JCO.2020.38.15_suppl.9048) of the study but still cannot get it. The article itself is behind a paywall.

Comment: Injection (as they're systemic not topical) as opposed to pill, patch etc, in the full document a key should be provided to say for certain, that's why this is a best guess, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'I' represents Intravenous infusion as it is mentioned in [Clinical trial information sheet](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT02125461).